# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]

Tags: java, apache, lifecycleexception

After deploying my war on my server I get the following error,

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext

 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/Converter
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2436)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:400)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

I have checked for the commons-beanutils.jar under WEB-INF/lib folder and it is present there. I have included it under the class path in my build.xml.

Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: Which version ob common-beanutils you have?

Comment: You are missing a dependency of Commons-beanutils

Comment: After deploying war did you check your commons-beanutils jar is there ?

Comment: which version of common-beanutils you are using?

Comment: Did you open the jar and see if Converter was actually there?

Comment: I am using this jar. commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar

Comment: Hi Sam, yes after deploying i checked under the folder WEB-INF/lib and it is present there

Comment: Hi Tech, The jar is working fine for another project. No problem with that.

Comment: seems like a version related issue, or may be you have two jars with different versions.

Comment: I used the latest version 1.9.2. Still it did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your server can't find the Converter class in org.apache.commons.beanutils package.Please also check your project build path to see if there is org.apache.commons.beanutils.converter class present or not. If not then 
Download the latest Commons-Utils jar and add it to in your lib folder.
You find the link [here]http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/index.html

Comment: does you find the " org.apache.commons.beanutils.Converter" class in your web-inf/lib folder and your build path???